# Stop meta refresh after a period of time

Tags: javascript, meta

Ok.  I know this is a dumb question.  I am working on these webcams for the different stores to put on our intranet site.   Here's the problem, trying to use the javascript code, the images don't display properly on one particular brand of camera.  (Axis)  Rather than displaying them in the iframe that my predecessor had them looking to, they make a scrollable window in the iframe if I use the js.   These originally had meta that would refresh every 7 seconds.  However, I know that each time it refreshes, the count starts over with meta and I cannot put a stop after a period of time.

So the meta tag that was there originally is ok, but doesn't allow for timeout.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
</head>

<script type="text/javascript">

var intervalID = 0;

function windowOnInitialize()
{
intervalID = setInterval("imageRefresher()", 7000);
//alert("we were called");
}

var counter = 0;

function imageRefresher()
{
//alert("we got to if statement");
if (counter < 46)
{
    counter++;
    //alert(counter);
    document.getElementById("theId").src="http://x.x.x.x:9524/cgi-bin/image.jpg?camera=right&size=320x240&quality=60" + Math.random();
 }
else
{
  //alert("");
  alert("Your Time is Up");
  clearInterval(intervalID);
```

That code works great for the other cams, just not the axis.   In particular just 2 models of axis.   So besides this, is there another way that I can tell the image to refresh every 7 seconds for a maximum of 46 refreshes before timing out?

Comment: I wanted to add one more thing to it.   If I use the js with the axis cams, then when it refreshes, it will not pull the image any longer unless I actually refresh the whole page.

Comment: That's not a meta-refresh. That's a javascript timer with a reload.

Comment: Correct.   The meta was in there initially with <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="7">

Comment: Ah. ok. you can put it back and use this: $('meta[http-equiv=refresh]').remove();